# Is this calculation correct? and why?

Tags: trigonometry

1st - is my value correct

2nd - Why or why not?

I have a regular hexagon, which i know the height is 2 units and width is also 2 units. I am trying to find the value for one of the sides.  I broke it down with triangles like so

[image: hex image]

now working with a 60,60,60 triangle, i know the Height of that triangle `h = height/2` which would be `1`

now i use `Altitude of Equilateral Triangle h = (1/2) * √3 * a`  Not knowing what `a` (side)

with this i get that a is 1.1547, thus each side is 1.1547.

BUT..

If i use this next
`B                   B
    *--*                *
   /|   \              /|
  / |    \            / |
A*--*C    *  ==>   c /  | a
  \      /          /   |
   \    /          /    |
    *--*         A*-----*C
                     b`

a 30 , 60, 90 triangle, it is telling me c (side of hex) is 1.1547 (got from other calculation) and a would be sqt(3)  which is 1.732...  Which is not half of my height like i would think it should be.  going by `c = 2, b = 1 and a = sqrt(3)`

So it makes me wonder what is the real way to find the side of a hex?

Comment: "the height is 2 units and width is also 2 units": that can't be, the hexagon does not inscribe inside a square.

Comment: "a would be sqt(3)": explain

Comment: the height from a top point to the bottom point is 2 units, and from left point to right point is 2 units

Comment: Well then it's not a regular hexagon, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyK so if (using image above) if 120 degree point to 240 degree point is 2 and 180 degree point to 0 degree point is 2 . That is not a regular hexagon? any reason why not?

Comment: Do you have a ruler at home? Just measure your diagram with it!

Comment: lol , its on a computer program, all i know is i set the width / height  and it draws it. but to tell it the next position to draw, i need to know the side value.

Comment: I'm serious. Measure the damned thing, _right there on the screen_, and you will see that the two distances are nowhere near equal.

Comment: @TonyK  The drawing above they are not equeal, as it was just a drawing.. but on the screen where i am programming the hex they are

Comment: @TonyK ok say i am 100 % wrong , and say i have a regular hexagon, how do i find out the side values?

Comment: If the width of the figure in your diagram is 2, then each side has length 1. And the height of the figure is $\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 1):

At the same time you say "c (side of hex) is 1.1547 (got from other calculation)", and "c = 2". This can't work.

Comment: The c=2 i found on how to calculate the sides of a 30,60,90 triangle.  the `c = 2, b = 1 and a = sqrt(3)`  is just an example of that. it is not values of my hex